# Сделать функцию аккумулирующую значения которые принимает (при неоднократном вызове)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть состоит в том чтобы получить функцию, которая сохраняет свое значение и значения переменных в своей области. Она принимает их и добавляет в список, затем при необходимости все накопленные данные возвращаются . Хотел реализовать с помощью генератора, но не получилось :

```
def acc(item=0,stop=0):
    buffer = []
    while item !=stop:
        buffer.append(item)
        yield "+"
    return buffer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование функции-генератора немного отличается от использования обычной функции. За основами можно обратиться к 20-й главе учебника "Изучаем Python" Марка Лутца. За просветлением к презентациям Дэвида Бизли - "[Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](https://www.dabeaz.com/generators/)", "[A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/)" и "[Generators: The Final Frontier](http://www.dabeaz.com/finalgenerator/)". Первый пример:

```
def acc():
    buf = []
    while True:
        # Получаем отправленные в генератор значения
        value, command = yield
        buf.append(value)
        if command:
            break
    yield buf

# Получаем генератор
g = acc()
# Инициализируем генератор
next(g)
# Отправляем в генератор значения
g.send((1, False))
g.send((2, False))
g.send((3, False))
# Получаем накопленные значения из генератора
items = g.send((4, True))
```

Избавимся от шага инициализации с помощью декоратора, а заодно от необходимости отправлять в генератор кортежи:

```
def coroutine(func):
    def init(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return init

@coroutine
def acc():
    buf = []
    while True:
        value = yield
        if value is StopIteration:
            break
        buf.append(value)
    yield buf

g = acc()
g.send(1)
g.send(2)
g.send(3)
items = g.send(StopIteration)
```

Теперь попробуем избавить от необходимости вызывать `send`:

```
def coroutine(func):
    def init(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return lambda x: cr.send(x)
    return init

@coroutine
def acc():
    ...

g = acc()
g(1)
g(2)
g(3)
items = g(StopIteration)
```

Такого же эффекта можно добиться с помощью *замыкания*:

```
def acc():
    buf = []
    def f(item):
        if item is None:
            return buf
        buf.append(item)
    return f

a = acc()
a(1)
a(2)
a(3)
items = a(None)
```

Или с помощью атрибутов функции (только в образовательных целях!):

```
def acc(item):
    if not hasattr(acc, '_buf'):
        acc._buf = []
    if item is None:
        items, acc._buf = acc._buf, []
        return items
    acc._buf.append(item)

acc(1)
acc(2)
acc(3)
items = acc(None)
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ и исчерпывающий ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Обязательно - как функция?

В виде класса это делается элементарно. Класс:

```
class Accum():

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def put(self, atom):
        self.list.append(atom)

    def get(self):
        return(self.list)
```

Использование класса:

```
x = Accum()

x.put(2)
x.put(10)
x.put(7)

print(x.get())
```

Не тестировал, поэтому могут быть ошибки. Но идея, я думаю, понятна.